Can the font used by the SAS Enterprise Guide file explorer be changed (to fixed font width)? I only find options for editor fonts
Using SAS EG 8.2 I find the variable width font of the file explorer quite annoying,
working with hundreds of folders, thousands of files with very similar names makes them hard to distinguish at a glance (i, l, 1, t, r, 0, O, Q).
Do they really simply use the "system default text font"?
Changing that would effect the complete system (and btw. can't even be changed in my currently used sh+tty, reduced Citrix environment).
No options for font settings can be found and no google search results besides for "editor font" or for processing results like reports, data tables and lists,and there are no corresponding help entries.
I would expect an option to select the fonts used in separate parts of the application,
not only in the editor window, but at least also in the server/file selection list.

I don't think it can but this is a great feature request. I recommend adding it as a product suggestion: https://communities.sas.com/t5/SAS-Product-Suggestions/idb-p/product-suggestions

If you can run SAS out of a local SAS/Studio session your interface is browser based and thus you can change browser user settings to tweak whatever aspect of the interface that you want.  You will need patience and luck to discover what element in the UI needs tweaking, even if you are a seasoned web "Inspector"

How to run SAS in a browser session? Again, it's the directory tree/file list I'm taling about. (If open in a browser windows, the inspect function helps to find about any element and its properties, available at least on Firefox.)

@Stu: I got no signin there - do you?
I miss the good old times of OS/2 where you simply dragged a  font, a color, a line style on any program window element to change whatever you liked. This technology got simply lost. FU, Microsoft!
